# Dynamic div with jQuery that shows content on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to work out the [demo at this site](http://www.designgala.com/demos/collapse-expand-jquery.html).
I'm having issues though.
Here's the code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".content").hide();
  jQuery(".heading").click(function() {
    jQuery(this).next(".content").slideToggle(500);
  });
});

var el = document.createElement('div');
el.className = "heading";
el.innerHTML = "whatever you want";
$('.listResults').append(el);

var el2 = document.createElement('div');
el2.className = "content";
el2.innerHTML = "whatever you want shown";
$('.listResults').append(el2);
jQuery(".content").hide();
```

HTML has a div with class called `listResults` to which everything gets appended. Currently the javascript is running after the load so I'm calling the `jQuery.hide` on `.content` once it's generated.

The problem is that when I click one of the header divs it doesn't drop down the content. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you [reproduce minimally/(sscce)](http://sscce.org/) your set-up with a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$('.listResults').on('click', '.heading',  function(){
    // whatever you want
});

var el = $('<div/>', {
    'class' : 'heading',
    'html' : 'whatever you want'
});
$('.listResults').append(el);
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/DLEBf/)

Alternatively you can also try this

```
var el = $('<div/>', {
    'class' : 'heading',
    'html' : 'whatever you want',
    'click' : function(){
        // whatever you want, you can use $(this)
    }
});

$('.listResults').append(el);
```

[**DEMO**.](http://jsfiddle.net/DLEBf/1/)

**Update:** This will create separate event handlers for each div and will consume more memory so it's not recommended but can use if you have a few divs.

[Updated Demo-1](http://jsfiddle.net/DLEBf/2/) and [Updated Demo-2.](http://jsfiddle.net/DLEBf/5/)

Comment: The second example works kind of. It doesn't unhide the content when clicked. I'm not sure how to do that either using your strategy. currently what i did was create another el using the content class. From there i need it to be hidden once created but then unhidden when the heading is clicked. is that possible?

Comment: I'm a little confused, can you please tell me what's your desired workflow with these divs ?

Comment: Like the site http://www.designgala.com/demos/collapse-expand-jquery.html where you click it and it shows content. unhides the content div

Comment: It's possible but where do you want to click to show/hide the div ? If the div is hidden then you need an element to click and unhide it.

Comment: <div id='listResults'> is the container. Within there is a <div class="heading"> which is what will be clickable. Once the heading is clicked it will show the <div class="content"> which is all generated by js/jquery.

Comment: Exactly how that site is but generated dynamically.

Comment: would     $('.listResults').on('click', '.heading',  function(){ not work if it was in a function already? i currently have it in function createMarker(latlng, address) { and it's not working..

Comment: This is what it looks like. http://jsfiddle.net/DLEBf/3/ . I tried to move it out. I'm not good with jquery at all.

Comment: @Denver, [Check this out](http://jsfiddle.net/DLEBf/5/) but you should have told/provide the details (markers/map) before.

Comment: wrapping $(function() { around my createmarker function breaks the code. any idea why? this is all i did: http://jsfiddle.net/HfT2d/

Comment: updated. sorry. all i did was add the function without any other changes. soon as i remove the $function code it runs

Answer (score 1):

You are create the div's at the runtime so use live binding , please read about live here

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: `.live()` has been deprecated since jQuery 1.7, you can tell if you read the documentation you are linking to

Answer (score 1):

I wouldnt use the live method, its depreciated and removed in 1.9. Your best option is to use the 'on' method when creating your div's. http://api.jquery.com/on/